VLC no longer plays WAV files, Windows 10, why?
I received a new computer, Windows 10 pro.  I installed the latest VLC. Now when I play .WAV files, all I hear is a little pop sound.
How do I fix this?

Windows Audio Enhancements, is causing the problem.  Uncheck the box and click OK. VLC player is working correctly.
